# Change the Text Orientation from Left-to-Right in Pyocr

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I'm using pyocr in conjunction with Pillow and OpenCV to extract text from PDF documents.  However, the PDF documents are forms which means, in some cases, the label of the item in the form is on the far left side of the document and the value of the item is on the right side of the document.  An example would be (dots added for spacing, but don't exist in image):

price of oranges:......................................$15.75

price of apples:.......................................$12.51

When I convert the image to text, it will look like this:

price of oranges:/nprice of apples/n$15.75/n$12.51

Basically, the text is being read top-to-bottom and then left-to-right versus left-to-right and then top-to-bottom.

In my research of this issue online, there are many answers which highlight how to detect orientation of text, but I already know that I want my text to flow from left-to-right in ALL CASES.  So, my question is, is there a way to change the default setting in pyocr so that it always reads text from left-to-right.  I want my converted text to look like this:

price of oranges: $15.75/n
price of apples: $12.51/n

Here is the code I'm currently using for pyocr:

```
def image_to_OCR(req_image_list,final_text):
tool = pyocr.get_available_tools()[0]
for img in req_image_list:
    txt = tool.image_to_string(
        PI.open(io.BytesIO(img)),
        lang='eng',
        builder=pyocr.builders.TextBuilder()
    )
    final_text.append(txt)
return(final_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

`tesseract` is made to do OCR even with column based image. So you cant specify the orientation. 
You can rotate the image by 90 and then do ocr

or

You can use `numpy` to convert image to array and then divide the images based on empty lines then save the images and do OCR.